CSV upload issue with UTF-8 and special characters
I have the following function:
processFiles(fileList) {
  this.loading = true; // Ladeindikator anzeigen
  Array.from(fileList).forEach(file => {
    const fileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    if (fileExtension === "csv" || file.type === "text/csv") {
      // CSV-Dateien mit PapaParse verarbeiten

      Papa.parse(file, {
        encoding: "UTF-8",
        complete: results => {
          const data = results.data;
          const cleanedData = data.filter(
            row => row.length && row.some(cell => cell.trim() !== "")
          );
          const columns = cleanedData[0];
          const dataRows = cleanedData.slice(1);

          this.tables.push({
            columns,
            data: dataRows,
            originalHeaders: columns
          });
          this.files.push({
            name: file.name,
            size: file.size,
            header: columns,
            firstRow: dataRows[0]
          });

          this.loading = false; // Ladeindikator verbergen
          this.step = 1; // Setze Schritt 1 als abgeschlossen
          this.CustomSnackbar = "Datei erfolgreich hochgeladen!"; // Snackbar-Nachricht setzen
          this.snackbarColor = "success"; // Setze die Snackbar-Farbe auf 'success'
          this.snackbar = true; // Snackbar anzeigen
        },

        error: error => {
          console.error("Fehler beim Parsen der CSV-Datei:", error);
          this.loading = false;
          this.CustomSnackbar = "Fehler beim Lesen der CSV-Datei!";
          this.snackbarColor = "error";
          this.snackbar = true;
        }
      });
    } else if (
      fileExtension === "xls" ||
      fileExtension === "xlsx" ||
      file.type ===
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    ) {
      // Excel-Dateien mit xlsx-Bibliothek verarbeiten
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => {
        const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });

        // Verwenden Sie das erste Arbeitsblatt
        const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];

        // Arbeitsblatt in JSON konvertieren
        const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });

        // Leere Zeilen entfernen
        const cleanedData = jsonData.filter(
          row =>
            row.length &&
            row.some(
              cell =>
                cell !== undefined &&
                cell !== null &&
                cell.toString().trim() !== ""
            )
        );

        // Erste Zeile als Spaltennamen verwenden
        const columns = cleanedData[0];

        // Datenzeilen
        const dataRows = cleanedData.slice(1);

        this.tables.push({ columns, data: dataRows, originalHeaders: columns });
        this.files.push({
          name: file.name,
          size: file.size,
          header: columns,
          firstRow: dataRows[0]
        });

        this.loading = false; // Ladeindikator verbergen
        this.step = 1; // Setze Schritt 1 als abgeschlossen
        this.CustomSnackbar = "Datei erfolgreich hochgeladen!";
        this.snackbarColor = "success";
        this.snackbar = true;
      };
      reader.onerror = error => {
        console.error("Fehler beim Lesen der Excel-Datei:", error);
        this.loading = false;
        this.CustomSnackbar = "Fehler beim Lesen der Excel-Datei!";
        this.snackbarColor = "error";
        this.snackbar = true;
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); // Datei als ArrayBuffer lesen
    } else {
      // Nicht unterstützter Dateityp
      this.loading = false;
      this.CustomSnackbar =
        "Ungültiger Dateityp! Bitte laden Sie eine CSV- oder  Excel-Datei hoch.";
      this.snackbarColor = "error";
      this.snackbar = true;
    }
  });
}

When I try to upload a CSV file with German characters like ä,ö,ü etc. then the data is displayed like this:
M�ller...
How can I solve this problem?
I tried to solve the issue with UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 etc but it didnt work

This question is similar to: Javascript export CSV encoding utf-8 issue. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
